# Cakephp Website URL input validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, cakephp

I tried some regular expressions for website URL validation that only accept URLs starting with `www.` (not `http://` or `https://`), but none fit my needs.

I tried : `(?<!:\/\/)www\..+\.[a-z]{2,3}`  but that accepts URLs with other characters before `www.`, like `adswww.website.com`.  I only want to accept URLs that start with `www.`.

cakephp v : 2.6

Comment: `(?<!\b(?:https|http):\/\/)www\.`

Comment: @AvinashRaj , it will give you an error in cakephp Model validation.

Comment: yes, preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'w' [CORE/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationRule.php, line 279]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by using

`/^www\..+\.[a-z]{2,3}/`

Answer (score 1):

You can try for example with:

```
(?<!:\/\/)www\..+\.[a-z]{2,3}
```

Comment: but it does accept swww.abc.com too. any solution? before www i dnt want anything.